# How to Add text qualifier and Escape char while Doing Bigquery Export

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I m trying to Export one table into GCP Csv File using below Query

```
EXPORT DATA
  OPTIONS ( uri = 'gs://Filepath/Filename*.csv',
    format = 'CSV',
    OVERWRITE = TRUE,
    header = TRUE,
    field_delimiter = ',') 
  AS (
  SELECT {Columns}
  FROM `tablename` order by {Columns} limit 10
  );
```

here as we can see we are able to Specify  field_delimeter , but can not set textqualifier/ escap char - as it doesn't have this feature as per documentation

how to overcome with this issue? how to make perfect CSV export from big Query to GCS?

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this @jeegnesh? If you're not aware, BQ EXPORT DATA does add double quotes around any field that includes the delimiter. It's clumsy and ugly, but should work in most use cases.